# Check If WKInterfaceTimer has Reached 0

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have a countdown timer in my watch app that works as intended and want to call a function once the timer reaches 0. How can I do this?

I have this right now.

```
let time = 10
timer = Timer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(time), target: self, selector: #selector(timerDone), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
countDownTimer.setDate(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(time)))
countDownTimer.start()

func timerDone() {
        countDownTimer.stop()
        countDownTimer.setHidden(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Start and stop timer by below mention code :-**

```
var refreshTimer = Timer()
func startTimer() {
    refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(InterfaceController.timerDone), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func stopTimer() {
    refreshTimer.invalidate()
}

func timerDone() {
    //countDownTimer.stop()
    //countDownTimer.setHidden(true)
}
```

Comment: I believe this will not fire if the app extension is in the background.